# How to validate a field in a GridView dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a field in a grid view called 'Financial Variance'. It is only enabled when there is a variance between 'FL Charge Cost' and 'Invoice Amount'. I need it to be required and show the validation error when enabled.

[image]

this is the code for the grid

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <dxg:GridControl
                x:Name="xgrdLgVendorInvoiceItem"
                Width="Auto"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                FontSize="12"
                IsManipulationEnabled="True"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="11"
                Loaded="xgrdLgVendorInvoiceItem_Loaded"

                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                SelectionMode="Row">
                <dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu>
                    <dxb:PopupMenu>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem
                            x:Name="xbbiAddvLgVendorInvoiceItem"
                            Content="Add Item"
                            Glyph="{dx:DXImageGrayscale Image=Add_16x16.png}"
                            ItemClick="xbbiAddvLgVendorInvoiceItem_ItemClick" />
                    </dxb:PopupMenu>
                </dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu>
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcChargeType"
                        Width="120"
                        MinWidth="80"
                        AllowEditing="True"
                        FieldName="LgChargeTypeId"
                        Header="Charge Type"
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxg:LookUpEditSettings
                                x:Name="xlueChargeType"
                                AutoPopulateColumns="False"
                                DisplayMember="Value"
                                FilterCondition="Contains"
                                ImmediatePopup="True"
                                ValueMember="Key">
                                <dxg:LookUpEditSettings.PopupContentTemplate>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl">
                                            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                                <dxg:GridColumn
                                                    x:Name="xgcChargeTypeId"
                                                    FieldName="Key"
                                                    Header="Id"
                                                    Visible="False" />
                                                <dxg:GridColumn
                                                    x:Name="xgcChargeType"
                                                    Width="40"
                                                    FieldName="Value"
                                                    Header="Charge Type" />
                                                <!--<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcBrandName" FieldName="Brand" Header="Brand" Width="150"/>-->
                                            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                                <dxg:TableView AllowBestFit="True" AutoWidth="True" />
                                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                        </dxg:GridControl>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </dxg:LookUpEditSettings.PopupContentTemplate>
                            </dxg:LookUpEditSettings>
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcInvoiceNumber"
                        Width="200"
                        FieldName="LgVendorInvoiceId"
                        Header="Invoice"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcLgVendorInvoiceItemId"
                        Width="200"
                        FieldName="LgVendorInvoiceItemId"
                        Header="Lg Vendor Invoice Item Id"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcLgVendorInvoiceId"
                        Width="200"
                        FieldName="LgVendorInvoiceId"
                        Header="Lg Vendor Invoice Id"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcChargeTypeId"
                        Width="200"
                        FieldName="LgChargeTypeId"
                        Header="Lg Charge Type Id"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcFLChargeCost"
                        Width="90"
                        MinWidth="80"
                        AllowEditing="False"
                        FieldName="FLChargeCost"
                        Header="FL Charge Cost"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                Mask="C"
                                MaskType="Numeric"
                                MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcInvoiceAmount"
                        Width="120"
                        MinWidth="80"
                        AllowEditing="True"
                        FieldName="InvoiceAmount"
                        Header="Invoice Amount"
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                Mask="C"
                                MaskType="Numeric"
                                MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>


                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcFLChargeId"
                        Width="90"
                        MinWidth="40"
                        AllowEditing="false"
                        FieldName="FLChargeId"
                        Header="FL Charge"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="False"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcCreatedBy"
                        Width="200"
                        FieldName="FullName"
                        Header="Created By"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcRecordDT"
                        Width="200"
                        AllowEditing="False"
                        FieldName="RecordDT"
                        Header="Record Date"
                        HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
                        ReadOnly="True"
                        Visible="False">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                DisplayFormat="d"
                                Mask="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <!--<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcChargeType"                     FieldName="ChargeType"                 Header="Charge Type"            Width="200"          ReadOnly="False"             AllowEditing="True"         HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"/>-->

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcLgFinancialVarianceTypeId"
                        Width="138"
                        MinWidth="80"
                        AllowEditing="true"
                        FieldName="LgFinancialVarianceTypeId"
                        Header="Financial Variance"
                        ReadOnly="False"
                        SortIndex="0"
                        SortOrder="Descending"
                        Visible="True">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxg:LookUpEditSettings
                                x:Name="xlueFinVarianceType"
                                AutoPopulateColumns="False"
                                DisplayMember="Value"
                                FilterCondition="Contains"
                                ImmediatePopup="True"
                                ValueMember="Key">
                                <dxg:LookUpEditSettings.PopupContentTemplate>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl">
                                            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                                <dxg:GridColumn
                                                    x:Name="xgcLgFinancialVarianceTypeId"
                                                    FieldName="Key"
                                                    Header="Id"
                                                    Visible="False" />
                                                <dxg:GridColumn
                                                    x:Name="xgcLgFinancialVarianceType"
                                                    Width="40"
                                                    FieldName="Value"
                                                    Header="Financial Variance Type" />
                                                <!--<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcBrandName" FieldName="Brand" Header="Brand" Width="150"/>-->
                                            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                                <dxg:TableView AllowBestFit="True" AutoWidth="True" />
                                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                        </dxg:GridControl>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </dxg:LookUpEditSettings.PopupContentTemplate>
                            </dxg:LookUpEditSettings>
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>

                    <dxg:GridColumn
                        x:Name="xgcComment"
                        Width="200"
                        AllowEditing="True"
                        FieldName="Comment"
                        Header="Comment"
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"
                        ReadOnly="False"
                        Visible="False" />




                    <!--<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcFinancialVarinace"                     FieldName="FinancialVariance"                 Header="Financial Variance"            Width="200"          ReadOnly="False"             AllowEditing="True"         HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"/>-->

                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView
                        x:Name="xgrvLgVendorInvoiceEdit"
                        AllowCascadeUpdate="True"
                        AllowColumnFiltering="False"
                        AllowFilterEditor="False"
                        AllowFixedGroups="True"
                        AllowGrouping="True"
                        CellValueChanged="xgrvvLgVendorInvoiceItem_CellValueChanged"
                        CellValueChanging="xgrvLgVendorInvoiceEdit_CellValueChanging"
                        FocusedRowHandleChanged="xgrvLgVendorInvoiceEdit_FocusedRowHandleChanged"
                        HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Auto"
                        MouseRightButtonDown="xgrvLgVendorInvoiceEdit_MouseRightButtonDown"
                        ShowFixedTotalSummary="True"
                        ShowGroupPanel="True"
                        ShowGroupedColumns="True"
                        ShowTotalSummary="False"
                        VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Auto">
                        <!--
                            ShowingEditor="xgrvvLgVendorInvoiceItem_ShowingEditor"
                            FocusedColumnChanged="xgrvvLgVendorInvoiceItem_FocusedColumnChanged"
                            CellValueChanging="xgrvTableView_CellValueChanging"
                            FocusedRowChanged="xgrvvLgVendorInvoiceItem_FocusedRowChanged"
                        -->


                        <dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                            <dxb:BarButtonItem
                                x:Name="xbbiAddRowvLgVendorInvoiceItem"
                                Content="Add Item"
                                Glyph="{dx:DXImageGrayscale Image=Add_16x16.png}"
                                ItemClick="xbbiAddvLgVendorInvoiceItem_ItemClick" />
                            <dxb:BarButtonItem
                                x:Name="xbbiDeletevLgVendorInvoiceItem"
                                Content="Delete Item"
                                Glyph="{dx:DXImageGrayscale Image=Remove_16x16.png}"
                                ItemClick="xbbiDeletevLgVendorInvoiceItem_ItemClick" />
                        </dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                    </dxg:TableView>
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </Grid>
```

the rule i have set for the other is

```
 BusinessRules.AddRule(new Csla.Rules.CommonRules.MinValue<Int32>(_ChargeTypeIdProperty, 1, "Charge type required"));
```

Comment: Can you show the code behind.

Comment: updated it to show the code